# Connecting an Android device to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, device

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad, and am trying to connect it to Eclipse. It was working a few weeks ago, but I haven't tried to run an application on it in a while and now will not show up in Eclipse.

It shows up in my LeTools...

[image]

But when I Run my application in Eclipse...

[image]

This error also comes up, but I think its a different problem...
[image]

Anyway, I think that I'm missing a minor step to get the Device to show up in Eclipse. If anyone knows what this step is, please let me know.

Comment: What in the world is LeTools? Also one thing you can try is reinstall the USB driver and reconnect the device.

Comment: Haha, LeTools is the Software distributed by Lenovo for their devices.

Comment: Can you check whether adb is running in your machine? you can also do a "adb start-server" if it isn't.

Comment: Try to uninstall the device and then install it again.. I think the your device port is the problem..

Comment: Don't know what that is or how to do it

Comment: Ah, this is shown in Eclipse when I press run... `[2012-07-23 11:52:45 - Singleton4] adb is running normally.`

Comment: Try "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server" doing this a few times fixes the issue for me. And I dont know what LeTools is.

Comment: Where do you want me to enter that? In a terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Well, it turns out that in that second screen shot, with the EMPTY list of running Android Devices, mine was actually there.

For some reason all the fields ( Serial Number, AVD Name, Target, etc. ), have been changed to an empty string.

Anyway, if I double-click on the first row of the blank list, it loads the app on my device.